# Ajax Control Toolkit CascadingDropDown

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

```
its aspx page:

    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="countriesddl" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="countriescdd" TargetControlID="countriesddl" PromptText="Select Country"
                    PromptValue="" ServicePath="~/servicecon.asmx" ServiceMethod="getcountries" runat="server" 
                    Category="countryid" LoadingText="Loading..."></asp:CascadingDropDown>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="stateddl" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="statecdd" TargetControlID="stateddl" PromptText="Select Country"
                    PromptValue="" ServicePath="~/servicecon.asmx" ServiceMethod="getstate" runat="server" 
                    Category="stateid" LoadingText="Loading..."></asp:CascadingDropDown>


its services.asmx page:

 [WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] getcountries(string knownCategoryValues)
    {
        string query = "select countryname , countryid from country";
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> country = getdata(query);
        return country.ToArray();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] getstate(string knownCategoryValues)
    {
        string countre = CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues)["countryid"];
        string query = string.Format("select statename, stateid from state where countryid = 0", countre);
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> state = getdata(query);
        return state.ToArray();
    }
    private List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> getdata(string query)
    {
        string constr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cdd"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> values = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue
                   {
                       name = rdr[0].ToString(),
                       value = rdr[1].ToString()
                   });
                }
                rdr.Close();
                con.Close();
                return values;
            }
        }
```

### in the above code works correctly for the first dropdownlist, for the second dropdownlist its not loading the data from the databse, ple help me, thanx in advance.....

---

dummy text

When you asking questions, using some more words to describe your problem will always help. If there are really nothing more to say, just copy some random paragraph from internet, but make sure you mark them as dummy text so that people won't pay attention on them.

Answer (score 0):

Does the second SQL return results when ran in Sql Server Management Studio? If the first query works with the same `getData` function it must be the data itself or the sql... If all four columns in both queries are strings, must be your SQL `where` is matching on nothing or there is no data.

You are sure there are states where `countryid = 0`?